# keys and mget is not atomic?

Tags: python, redis, atomic

I have a case:

```
# a = r.keys("test_*") ; a 
{'test_1': '1', 'test_2': '2'}
# b = r.mget(a) ; b
['1', ''2]
```

But `test_1` may timeout when `mget`. So How can I make `keys` and `mget` as atomic step to make

```
 dict(zip(keys, r.mget(keys))
```

always get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make these two commands running atomically, you can use lua scripting.

```
--atomic.lua
local keys = redis.call('keys', '*')
local result = {}
for idx, key in ipairs(keys) do
    table.insert(result, key)   -- insert key
    table.insert(result, redis.call('get', key))    -- insert value
end
return result
```

**However, it's almost always a BAD idea to use the `KEYS` command**, since it might block Redis for a long time.

Comment: I am not sure.  The  ```redis.call('get', key)```  may not exist . May be another program del the key after call `keys`

Comment: @jiamo Since lua script runs in atomic way, others CANNOT `del` the key when the script is still running.